# Rails Paperclip skip upload if image is already present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

Im trying to do an import of thousands of items and most of them use the same image. I want to check before uploading the image if one already exists with the same name so that I can save time and also the resources. I am using amazon s3 as storage. I cant seem to find anything in the documentation about it. I know that I can do something like image.exists? but what do I do in the model to not upload the image but still set everything in the database to point to the existing image.

Rails 3.2.12
Paperclip 3.2.1

```rb
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/pjpeg']

has_attached_file :image,
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
                :path => "images/:attachment/:style/:filename",
                :styles => { :original => '64x64', :small => '32x32' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this exact problem before as well, and never completely found a solution for this.  I think it's because of the design of Paperclip that every record needs a unique attachment.

You could try to do something like [copying an existing attachment to another record](http://makandracards.com/makandra/6-copy-a-paperclip-attachment-to-another-record), but that will still upload the "copied" attachment to the record.

The best alternative I could find (without forking and trying to monkeypatch Paperclip) was to move processing of attaching files to a background job, like Resque.  This will offload the time part of your concern.  As for the resources, S3 is pretty cheap - I've never been above $0.15 for my S3 instance with hundreds of thousands of images, but it's a site that doesn't get much traffic.

Comment: Yeah I was more worried about saving time on my import and not having 15000 of the same image.

Comment: I hear you.  But moving it to something like Resque will make that impact less apparent.

Comment: What if I remove the actual image from the process before save and manually update the database with the fields from the file. Would this work?

Comment: If I follow what you're saying correctly, that *might* work, but only if Paperclip respects calls like `update_column` which bypass callbacks.